# Is it possible to copy files from one folder to another using an excel file list in RStudio?

Tags: r, csv

I need to copy files from one folder to another. But they are not all, I have a list in excel with the names of the files I need to copy in the same directory, is it possible to use this list in a code to copy the specific files? At this moment I was trying with:

```
setwd("E:/Soundtrap/500 hz")
getwd()  

lista1=barco_D

for (archivo in lista1)
file.copy(from= archivo, to= paste("E:/Soundtrap/500 hz/barco_D")))
```

Here setwd is the folder where the files are, list1 is the excel the list of file names. But I don't know how to put in the code that the files that are copied from the folder "500 hz" to the folder "ship_D" are the ones in list1. If you can help me :c

Comment: Please provide the input in a reproducible manner as well as the expected output and the rules to get from one to another. Also show your best attempt using R code to solve the problem.  Note that problems should be expressed in a minimal manner. Please remove excess verbiage not needed to solve the problem.  See the info at the top of the [tag:r] tag page.

Comment: Clear yes, it's possible to read csv files! Now, anything that has to do with data needs examples, ideally max 10 rows/columns that represent the data/problem adequately (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.